# Mongo: Update value of string array element using the element itself

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I have an **express** app, and I am using **mongodb** for my DB needs. My collection structure is as follow.

Collection has documents like the one below.

```
{
    _id: 5caa266c58b170106ff17f40,
    title: "Test2 88 bulkWrite",
    last_save_date: 2019-04-07T17:08:25.149+00:00,
    created_by: "McufNwnQX8YXC0tNSa1fdbt9Tus2",
    stories: [ { story_id: "1", objects: [...] },
               { story_id: "2", objects: [...] },
               { story_id: "3", objects: [...] },
                ... 
             ]    
 }
```

The ask is simple, when let's say a user clicks a button, the array element `{story_id: "2", objects: [...]}` is deleted, and all the elements with `story_id` of more than "2" ( s.a., "3", "4"...) are decremented by one (become "2" and "3").

The first part, i.e., delete has been accomplished, but it's the second part which eludes me.
Here is the code:

```
var storyId = ... (fetch from a request);
var intStoryId = parseInt( storyId) ;

var arrayOfHigherNumber = function() {
    var temp = [];
    if ( intStoryId == 5 ) { return temp; }
    for ( var i = intStoryId + 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
        temp.push( i.toString() );
    }
    return temp;
}

collection.bulkWrite([
// This works and is able to delete the particular story_id entry
    { updateOne: {
        'filter': {'_id' : ObjectID( docId ) },
        'update': { 
            '$pull': { 'stories': { 'story_id': storyId } }
        }
    }},
// This does NOT work. 
    { updateMany: {
        'filter': { '_id': ObjectID( docId ), 'story_id': { '$in': arrayOfHigherNumber() } },
        'update': {
            '$set': { 'stories': { 'story_id': ( parseInt( 'story_id', 10 ) - 1 ).toString() } 
         }
     }
   }}
])
```

I have been banging my head against the wall for the last 24 hours and have tried many approaches, including `NumberInt`, `$int`, `$convert`, and several more such as aggregation pipelines, but I have not been able to accomplish this. It seems simple to be accomplished easily, but alas! Please note the story_id is a string, hence it's not that straightforward to use, let's say, a `$inc` operator.

**EDIT**

Answer by Anthony Winzlet is correct. I handled it just a bit differently, that's all.

My method

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": ObjectID( docId) },
    { "$pull": { "stories": { "story_id": storyId } } },
    { returnOriginal: false }
)
.then( function( story ) {
    collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        { "_id" : ObjectID( docId ) },
        { "$set": {
            "stories": story.value.stories.map(a => {
                if ( parseInt( a.story_id, 10 ) > parseInt( storyId, 10 ) ) {
                    return { story_id: (parseInt( a.story_id, 10 ) - 1).toString(), objects: a.objects }
                } else {
                    return { story_id: a.story_id , objects: a.objects }
                }
            })
        }}
    )
    .then( function ( result ) {
        response.send( result );
        client.close();
    })
})
```

Comment: Firstly you cannot use the aggregation operators inside the update query. And second what is the type of the `story_id` field?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet It is a string.

Comment: It will be better if you can change it to integer value and then you can easily use `arrayFilters` to update the `story_id`. If not then you have to use iteration using `find` query first and then will have to `update`.

Comment: Actually I thought of that earlier as well, but as per my logic a whole JSON is being saved as a document, and I have no control for a pre-conversion in JS using NumberInt, etc. before adding the collection in the DB. However, `find` seems promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of bulk query use two operations using `async await`

```
const story = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id" : ObjectID( docId ) },
  { "$pull": { "stories": { "story_id": storyId } }},
  { "new": true }
)

const update = await collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "_id" : ObjectID( docId ) },
  { "$set": {
    "stories": story.stories.map((a, i) => { if (parseInt(a.story_id) > parseInt(story_id)) return { story_id: parseInt(a.story_id) + 1 }})
  }}
)
```

Comment: This seems promising, what is `story` here in `story.stories.map(...)` ? Should that be a positional operator, s.a., $ ? Running it in the same form will throw Reference Error

Comment: What is the error? And it should be `$set` operator. Updated the answer

Comment: Yeah I could get it'd be `$set`. Error: ReferenceError: story is not defined

Comment: Check my above both the query I have defined the `story` in the first query. So not possible

Comment: Let me check it more thoroughly, because logically you are right and everything should work.

Comment: Solved, the actual issue was `new` was not recognised by the driver ( `returnOriginal: false` was the accepted one). Your code is perfect. Hence, I am accepting your answer. Thanks a thousand times.

Answer (score 0):

collection.updateMany({ story_id : { $gte : deletedElementNo } }, { $inc : { story_id: -1 } });

I think this is something of the sort you are looking for?

Comment: story_id is a string unfortunately.